# Sort PDF Files based on last 7 Characters

Tags: arcpy, sorting, map-book

I have a Python script that creates PDF Map Books from pre-existing map PDFs, created in ArcGIS Pro. The PDF file names end with the month abbreviation and year they are associated with (example: CACumulativeSumWithin3000_SanBruno_Dec2017.pdf). I want to order the PDFs in the Map Book based on these final 7 charcacters, but the problem is it orders the PDFs alphabetically, so Apr2018 is first instead of Jan2018.

How can I order these PDFs using the month abbreviation and year?

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = r"E:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\Export\Cumulative_CA2"
path =  r"E:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\Export\Cumulative_CA2"

### Create PDF Map Book File
CApdfPath = os.path.join(path, 'SanBruno_CumulativeHeatMaps.pdf')

CApdfDoc = arcpy.mp.PDFDocumentCreate(CApdfPath)

### List all files in the output folder
CApdfList = arcpy.ListFiles( "CACumulativeSumWithin3000_SanBruno_*")

### Add market title page to the newly created PDF document
CApdfDoc.appendPages(os.path.join(path, "CATitlePage.pdf"))


### Append market specific pages to the PDF
for CApdf in CApdfList:

    print(CApdf)

    CApdfDoc.appendPages(r"E:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\Export\Cumulative_CA2\%s"%CApdf)
    print(CApdf)


CApdfDoc.saveAndClose()
```

Comment: @BERA I've tried that, but it still sorts alphabetically

Comment: @BERA It still does it alphabetically. Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong location. Do you mind inserting it into the code I've already posted?

Comment: @BERA Yes, I want to sort by the actual date. Sorry if I was unclear in my question.

Comment: As indicated by @BERA's answer this is a pure Python question that does not require ArcPy to create a code snippet that illustrates where you are stuck. Consequently, it should be researched at [so].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try sorting CApdfList using the datetime module and a lambda function. Insert the sorting after your comment: `### Append market specific pages to the PDF`

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime

CApdfList = ['CACumulativeSumWithin3000_SanBruno_Apr2017.pdf','CACumulativeSumWithin3000_SanBruno_Jan2014.pdf']

CApdfList.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[-11:-4],'%b%Y'))

>>CApdfList
['CACumulativeSumWithin3000_SanBruno_Jan2014.pdf', 'CACumulativeSumWithin3000_SanBruno_Apr2017.pdf']
```

To understand `'%b%Y'` see: [strptime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)